# JavaScript onClick function to trigger ActionsScript3 Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, actionscript, externalinterface

**Before I begin** I will explain that I am relatively new to ActionScript, also *newish* to JavaScript but have a handle on what I can/need to do.

I have done some hunting online to find out what is needed to do this, however I am not 100% sure on how to do it.

The only tutorials I am able to find are about sending text from one to the other and vice versa.

#### What I am trying to achieve:

> **[JavaScript]**
>
> > *HTML element is clicked.*
>
> **[ActionScript]**
>
> > *Performs an Event and passes Boolean back to JavaScript on success/error.*
>
> **[JavaScript]**
>
> > *Dependent on true/false will have methods in place to continue.*

**I am NOT asking you to do this for me**, however if you know of any good documentation/tutorials that you can point me to I would appreciate it. I am wanting to learn how to do this, not get shown/told how to do it.

#### Tutorials I have already read:

- [tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-and-actionscript-converse-introduction-to-externalinterface--active-893)
- [circlecube](http://circlecube.com/2010/12/actionscript-as3-javascript-call-flash-to-and-from-javascript/)

#### *AGAIN* thanks for any help / useful links that come my way :)

Comment: That first tutorial takes you through the whole process of JavaScript to ActionScript communication and back again. What more do you need to know?

Comment: My issues with these tutorials is that they are aiming at sending text data to each other, using the stage to display. What I am trying to do is where the stage is not visible, and the only interaction is to fire off a function / event in ActionScript when my JavaScript detects an onClick function. In **BOTH** tutorials they are aimed at using the stage and a TextField, and I am struggling to find something a little more comprehensive

Comment: The use of the TextField is irrelevant I think. What both those tutorials are giving you is essentially a hello world for JS - AS communication via ExternalInterface. I'd suggest following one of the tutorials and then adapting it to your purposes. Then when you run into a problem come back with a more specific question. I doubt there's a tutorial out there which addresses your particular requirements exactly and at the moment, your question is not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: *My point* here was that these tutorials are aimed at sending text data to and fro. I am looking to action something on a click. I am looking for **tutorials** or **good documentation** as the Adobe documentation is more of a puzzle than a handbook. I have already followed these tutorials, yet I am **still** none the wiser on what is required to achieve what I need. So I posted this to StackOverflow in the aim that a more experienced programmer may point me in the right direction - *NOT* belittle my question and tell me it doesn't belong on a website focused around answering these questions

Comment: It wasn't my intention to belittle your question and if that's how it's come across I'm sorry. However, your question is off-topic according to the rules of stackoverflow see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Point taken, perhaps my wording made this more off topic than was intended. I am simply trying to find a way to get ActionScript to trigger an event based on JavaScript actions. Whether this be here is some **simple stupid example code** or a simple **you need to investigate ExternalInterface.getMeWhatINeed** - you get the idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63581/discussion-between-steve-king-and-net-uk-sweet).

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the tutorial is attempting to show requesting calls from both sides and call backs on both sides is confusing you. I think the important steps, for you, are 16-18. In addition, I would point out that in step 18, if you remove where the text field is set, and replace it with a `ExternalInterface.call("responseFromAS", myBoolean);` Then make sure you have a JS function called **responseFromAS**. Aside from basic setup, those three steps should get you 80% to where you want to be. If you get stuck with this, then post your code and we can better instruct from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I have been reading article after tutorial after article since posting. So basically I can post a Boolean each way and in the AS3 I can - if this is true run my function? Then post back a Boolean back to a JavaScript function. Perhaps it was the whole textField part that confused me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found a possible answer to my prayers!

A very nice gentleman on [REDDIT](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/2k6oj5/stackoverflow_question_help_appreciated/) pointed out the best way for me to achieve this.

Every tutorial / suggestion I could find was doing it the opposite way to what was required.

I needed **[ACTIONSCRIPT]** to have an *Event* fire when a **[JAVASCRIPT]** element was triggered *onClick* so that a function could be called.

The answer given to me was :

> Register a handler in Flash with:
>
> `ExternalInterface.addCallback('jsFunction', asHandler);`
>
> After this I can call my function in JavaScript on the Flash Movie Object.

This appears to work, I will leave this question open for the next couple of days to see if anyone has any objections to this being the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, this is step 17 and 18 in the tutorial we were talking about.